# Java MySQL PreparedStatement SELECT Statement

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I have a database and a Java Program. I am trying to write a code, so that if in a textfield a MockID is entered, and the submit button is pressed, the details according to that entered Mock ID should be retrieved from the database and displayed in a textarea. below is the code that i have written. The code now works after amendments i have made. However, in the textarea, its not actually displaying the relevant information from that record for the given Mock Id, but just text.
Could someone please advise ?

```
    JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


        String mockId = textField.getText();    

        try {

            String sql = "SELECT MockID, Subject, Year, Date FROM mockexam WHERE MockID =?";    

            PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            prest.setString(1, mockId);

            prest.executeQuery();
            textArea.append("MockID, Subject, Year, Date");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmFindMock, "Record has been updated.");


        }

        catch (SQLException e) {
        //System.out.println("Record couldn't be added!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmFindMock, "Record couldn't be updated. Please try again.");
        }
        }

        });

    button.setBounds(303, 60, 75, 23);
    panel_1.add(button);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ? is the bind variable placeholder. you only have 1. so why are you trying to bind 4 things?

Answer (score 5):

```
        String sql = "SELECT MockID, Subject, Year, Date FROM mockexam WHERE MockID =?";    

        PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        prest.setString(1, "MockID");
        prest.setString(2, "Subject");
        prest.setString(3, "Year");
        prest.setString(4, "Date");
```

This is the problem. In your sql string you made room for 1 argument (indicated by the `?`) but then you tried to set 4. Hence you went of out bounds. Also since you hard coded the MockID, Subject, Year, and Date into the statement there is no reason to use `setString` to try set them (incorrectly).

To display the answer in your do this:

```
ResultSet rs = prest.executeQuery();
String result;
while(rs.next()) {
    String id = rs.getString("MockID");
    String subject = rs.getString("Subject");
    String year = rs.getString("Year");
    String Date = rs.getString("Date");
    result += id + ", " + subject + ", " + year + ", " + date + "\n";
}
textarea.append(result);
```

Comment: I would like Mock ID, Subject, Year and Date to be displayed as results in the TextArea. Reason why i had WHERE MockID =? is because the information should be displayed for a particular MockID that a user enters?

Comment: For example: `String sql = "SELECT MockID, Subject, Year, Date FROM mockexam WHERE MockID =?";    

        PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        prest.setString(1, "1");` 
Will select the `COLUMNS` MockID, Subject, Year, and Date from the database for any entry with a `MockID=1`

Comment: Oh i see what you mean. I shall try and amend the code, as I know understood what you meant :)

Comment: I have amended the code to prest.setString (1, mockId);. It partly works now, but its not actually displaying the relavant data from the record in the database instead its display as text: Mock ID, Subject, Year, Date. This is the code i have for the textarea:     textArea.append("Mock ID, Subject, Year, Date");

Comment: That's because you appended the String MockID Subject Year Date to the text area you have to get the ResultSet from the Database and get that data out of the resultSet. I'll Add the code for that Give me a sec.

Answer (score 1):

Your `PreparedStatement` only has one variable..i.e `MockID`

SELECT MockID, Subject, Year, Date FROM mockexam WHERE MockID =?....so following statements

```
                prest.setString(2, "Subject");
                prest.setString(3, "Year");
                prest.setString(4, "Date");
```

are not required.

`Update for your comments` :

we do `setString` for all the variables which are represented by "?"....and here only MockId is a variable.....you can retrieve the whole row if you want by using "select *"...but still there will be only one argument(represented by ?) to `PreparedStatement` and that is your `MockId`.

Comment: I would like Mock ID, Subject, Year and Date to be displayed as results in the TextArea. Reason why i had WHERE MockID =? is because the information should be displayed for a particular MockID that a user enters?

Comment: Yes I know...we do setString for all the variables which are represented by "?"....and here only MockId is a variable.....you can retrieve the whole row if you want by using "select *"...but still there will be only one argument(represented by ?) to PreparedStatement and that is your MockId

Answer (score 0):

"Date" is not a good choice for a column name.  It's a reserved word in every database I know of.  It's not very informative for users, either.  Birth date?  Death date?  Order date?  What does it mean?

I'd start by changing to "EXAM_DATE" or something else and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql = "SELECT MockID, Subject, Year, Date FROM mockexam WHERE MockID =?";
```

When preparing this statement, you "say" that you will give a value for each `?`. 
Here you only have one but you define 4 of them later on :

```
    PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    prest.setString(1, "MockID");
    prest.setString(2, "Subject");
    prest.setString(3, "Year");
    prest.setString(4, "Date");
```

And don't forget to close your connection, statement and possible result set to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: I would like Mock ID, Subject, Year and Date to be displayed as results in the TextArea. Reason why i had WHERE MockID =? is because the information should be displayed for a particular MockID that a user enters?