# how to check whether a string is present in the database table

Tags: java, jdbc

```
 String s="abcd";  // The user that needs to be excluded in the table, 
 the string can be dynamic.

 String sql="SELECT Username,Email FROM login where not 
 Username=userName"; //here I use the query not to exclude the particular user.


 PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
 ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
 while(rs.next()){
   inputString=(String)rs.getString("Username");                        
   model.addRow(new Object[{rs.getString("Username"),rs.getString("Email"),false});

 }
```

But the result produced is empty the other user's details were also excluded.

Comment: Username=userName in the SQL means every record. And in combination with not it means no record.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621428/java-mysql-preparedstatement-select-statement for binding parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try the modified query and also pass parameter dynamically as mentioned below.

```
// The user that needs to be excluded in the table, the string can be dynamic.
String s="abcd";  

//here I use the query not to exclude the particular user.
String sql="SELECT Username,Email FROM login where Username != ?"; 

PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstatement.setString(1, s);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```